# dask read_csv upcasts bool to object

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am working with monthly transaction files for which I have to do an analysis for a whole year, which does not fit in memory. So I am using dask to do this.

Firstly I processed my files in pandas such that it would be the most efficient dataframe in size (11 columns with 3 bools and 8 int's) and wrote these to csv from pandas. If I reread them via pandas, the types match what they should be. However if I read it in via Dask, the 3 bool columns get typed as objects, which take up a lot more memory.

I checked if it was a problem of mixed types but since I made the bool columns in pandas by adding a new columns with initiated values False and then changing this value to True based on some condition I did not find any missing values or None.

I also tried adding the dtypes to the read_csv command, which should pass it to the pandas read_csv but this doesn't change the types, they still end up as objects.

Is there a way around this or am I just missing something?

-Milan

Edit:
@MRocklin 
I don't do more than the following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

import pandas as pd

Transaction_folder = 'localpath/Transactions_*.csv.bz2'

trans_reader = pd.read_csv('localpath/Transactions_2016.csv.bz2', nrows = 100000) #to check if reading in 1 file via pandas works as expected

trans_reader.dtypes # gives bools and ints as expected
```

but then:

```
df = dd.read_csv(Transaction_folder, compression = 'bz2')

df.dtypes # gives ints and floats for the right columns but objects for everything that was bool
```

Could it be because of the compression?

Comment: Are you able to produce a small failing example.  My attempts to reproduce this error result in correct behavior (dd.read_csv returns a dataframe with bool dtyped columns).

Comment: @MRocklin I made an edit to the question with what I do